# Emacs lisp. One function to has no access to variables in another function

Tags: elisp

Code in emacs lisp:

(defun test-sub-fun-var()
  (message "SUB test-sub-fun-var: my-local-var: %s" my-local-var)
  )

(defun test-main()
  (message "\nSTART test-main")
  (let
      (
       (my-local-var)
       )
    (setq my-local-var "MY LOCAL VARIABLE VALUE")
    (message "MAIN my-local-var: %s" my-local-var)
    (test-sub-fun-var)
    )
  (message "FINISH test-main")
  )

(test-main)

When run function "test-main" we have result:

START test-main

MAIN my-local-var: MY LOCAL VARIABLE VALUE

SUB test-sub-fun-var: my-local-var: MY LOCAL VARIABLE VALUE

FINISH test-main

As you can see, the function "test-sub-fun-var" has access to variable "**my-local-var**" that declare in function "test-main". But I need function "test-sub-fun-var" to has NO access to variable "**my-local-var**". How I can do this? Thanks.

Comment: Read about dynamic binding and lexical binding in the manual. You want to enable lexical binding for your library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't say what version of Emacs you're using. Before 24.1 there wasn't really a way to do what you want, you just had to be careful. But, quoting from the latest version of the Info manual (26.0.50.1):

> ### 11.9.3 Lexical Binding
>
> Lexical binding was introduced to Emacs, as an optional feature, in
>   version 24.1. [...]
>   A lexically-bound variable has “lexical scope”, meaning that any
>   reference to the variable must be located textually within the binding
>   construct.

You enable lexical binding on a per-file basis, with the file-local variable `lexical-binding`. So,

```
;; -*- lexical-binding:t -*-

(defun test-sub-fun-var()
  (message "SUB test-sub-fun-var: my-local-var: %s" my-local-var))
(defun test-main()
   (message "\nSTART test-main")
   (let ((my-local-var))
       (setq my-local-var "MY LOCAL VARIABLE VALUE")
       (message "MAIN my-local-var: %s" my-local-var)
       (test-sub-fun-var))
   (message "FINISH test-main"))

(test-main)
```

Now your output is:

```
START test-main
MAIN my-local-var: MY LOCAL VARIABLE VALUE
test-sub-fun-var: Symbol’s value as variable is void: my-local-var
```

Comment: my Emacs version is 24.5.1

Comment: Then you should be OK. Just use lexical-binding: t.

Comment: You're very welcome! Please consider marking it as the solution, then.